# 2D Convolution Incorrect Results Cuda Constant Memory

Tags: cuda, gpu, convolution

I'm struggling in the kernel code. *I have updated this to include support files, but those were provided and should be correct.*

This is one of my first GPU programs and I've spent several hours trying new things and I can't seem to get this right. It is compiling and running, but the results are incorrect.

I am basically having trouble understanding what exactly I need to be doing differently because this kernel is giving incorrect results. I'm trying to load a tile of the input image to shared memory (Ns[][], which I think I've done correctly) and apply the filter on the input image tile (which I am struggling with).

I would greatly appreciate it if someone who is more experienced could assist me in figuring out exactly where I've gone wrong and give me an idea how to resolve the issue. I appreciate your time and apologies if I've asked this question incorrectly.

main.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "support.h"
#include "kernel.cu"
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
Timer timer;
time_t t;


// Initialize host variables ----------------------------------------------

printf("\nSetting up the problem..."); fflush(stdout);
startTime(&timer);

Matrix M_h, N_h, P_h; // M: filter, N: input image, P: output image
Matrix N_d, P_d;
unsigned imageHeight, imageWidth;
cudaError_t cuda_ret;
dim3 dim_grid, dim_block;

/* Read image dimensions */
if (argc == 1) {
    imageHeight = 600;
    imageWidth = 1000;
} else if (argc == 2) {
    imageHeight = atoi(argv[1]);
    imageWidth = atoi(argv[1]);
} else if (argc == 3) {
    imageHeight = atoi(argv[1]);
    imageWidth = atoi(argv[2]);
} else {
    printf("\n    Invalid input parameters!"
       "\n    Usage: ./convolution          # Image is 600 x 1000"
       "\n    Usage: ./convolution <m>      # Image is m x m"
       "\n    Usage: ./convolution <m> <n>  # Image is m x n"
       "\n");
    exit(0);
}

/* Allocate host memory */
M_h = allocateMatrix(FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE);
N_h = allocateMatrix(imageHeight, imageWidth);
P_h = allocateMatrix(imageHeight, imageWidth);

/* Initialize filter and images */
initMatrix(M_h);
initMatrix(N_h);

stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));
printf("    Image: %u x %u\n", imageHeight, imageWidth);
printf("    Mask: %u x %u\n", FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE);

// Allocate device variables ----------------------------------------------

printf("Allocating device variables..."); fflush(stdout);
startTime(&timer);

N_d = allocateDeviceMatrix(imageHeight, imageWidth);
P_d = allocateDeviceMatrix(imageHeight, imageWidth);

cudaDeviceSynchronize();
stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

// Copy host variables to device ------------------------------------------

printf("Copying data from host to device..."); fflush(stdout);
startTime(&timer);

/* Copy image to device global memory */
copyToDeviceMatrix(N_d, N_h);
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M_h, M_c,FILTER_SIZE*sizeof(float));

 dim_grid = dim3(((N_h.width / BLOCK_SIZE) + 1), ((N_h.height / BLOCK_SIZE) + 1));
 dim_block = dim3(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);


cudaDeviceSynchronize();
stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

// Launch kernel ----------------------------------------------------------
printf("Launching kernel..."); fflush(stdout);
startTime(&timer);


convolution<<<dim_grid, dim_block>>>(N_d, P_d);

cuda_ret = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
if(cuda_ret != cudaSuccess) FATAL("Unable to launch/execute kernel");

cudaDeviceSynchronize();
stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

// Copy device variables from host ----------------------------------------

printf("Copying data from device to host..."); fflush(stdout);
startTime(&timer);

copyFromDeviceMatrix(P_h, P_d);

cudaDeviceSynchronize();
stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

// Verify correctness -----------------------------------------------------

printf("Verifying results..."); fflush(stdout);

verify(M_h, N_h, P_h);

// Free memory ------------------------------------------------------------

freeMatrix(M_h);
freeMatrix(N_h);
freeMatrix(P_h);
freeDeviceMatrix(N_d);
freeDeviceMatrix(P_d);

return 0;
}
```

kernel.cu:

```
__constant__ float M_c[FILTER_SIZE][FILTER_SIZE];
__global__ void convolution(Matrix N, Matrix P){

__shared__ float Ns[TILE_SIZE + 5 - 1][TILE_SIZE + 5 -1];
int i, j;
float output = 0.0f;
int tx = threadIdx.x;
int ty = threadIdx.y;
int row_o = blockIdx.y * TILE_SIZE + ty;
int col_o = blockIdx.x * TILE_SIZE + tx;
int row_i = row_o - 2;
int col_i = col_o - 2;                  
if((row_i >= 0) && (row_i < N.height) && (col_i >= 0) && (col_i < N.width)){
        Ns[ty][tx] = N.elements[row_i * N.width + col_i];           
}
else{
        Ns[ty][tx] = 0.0f;
}
__syncthreads();
if(ty < TILE_SIZE && tx < TILE_SIZE){
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                output += M_c[i][j] * Ns[i + ty][j + tx];
                }
        }
}
if(row_o < P.height && col_o < P.width){
        P.elements[row_o * P.width + col_o] = output;
}
}
```

support.h:

```
#ifndef __FILEH__
#define __FILEH__

#include <sys/time.h>

typedef struct {
    struct timeval startTime;
    struct timeval endTime;
} Timer;

// Matrix Structure declaration
typedef struct {
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int pitch;
    float* elements;
} Matrix;

#define FILTER_SIZE 5
#define TILE_SIZE 12
#define BLOCK_SIZE (TILE_SIZE + FILTER_SIZE - 1)

Matrix allocateMatrix(unsigned height, unsigned width);
void initMatrix(Matrix mat);
Matrix allocateDeviceMatrix(unsigned height, unsigned width);
void copyToDeviceMatrix(Matrix dst, Matrix src);
void copyFromDeviceMatrix(Matrix dst, Matrix src);
void verify(Matrix M, Matrix  N, Matrix P);
void freeMatrix(Matrix mat);
void freeDeviceMatrix(Matrix mat);
void startTime(Timer* timer);
void stopTime(Timer* timer);
float elapsedTime(Timer timer);

#define FATAL(msg, ...) \
do {\
    fprintf(stderr, "[%s:%d] "msg"\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
    exit(-1);\
} while(0)

#if __BYTE_ORDER != __LITTLE_ENDIAN
# error "File I/O is not implemented for this system: wrong endianness."
#endif
#endif
```

support.cu:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "support.h"

Matrix allocateMatrix(unsigned height, unsigned width)
{
    Matrix mat;
    mat.height = height;
    mat.width = mat.pitch = width;
    mat.elements = (float*)malloc(height*width*sizeof(float));
    if(mat.elements == NULL) FATAL("Unable to allocate host");

    return mat;
}

void initMatrix(Matrix mat)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat.height*mat.width; i++) {
        mat.elements[i] = (rand()%100)/100.00;
    }
}

Matrix allocateDeviceMatrix(unsigned height, unsigned width)
{
    Matrix mat;
    cudaError_t cuda_ret;

    mat.height = height;
    mat.width = mat.pitch = width;
    cuda_ret = cudaMalloc((void**)&(mat.elements), height*width*sizeof(float));
    if(cuda_ret != cudaSuccess) FATAL("Unable to allocate device memory");

    return mat;
}

void copyToDeviceMatrix(Matrix dst, Matrix src)
{
    cudaError_t cuda_ret;
    cuda_ret = cudaMemcpy(dst.elements, src.elements, src.height*src.width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if(cuda_ret != cudaSuccess) FATAL("Unable to copy to device");
}

void copyFromDeviceMatrix(Matrix dst, Matrix src)
{
    cudaError_t cuda_ret;
    cuda_ret = cudaMemcpy(dst.elements, src.elements, src.height*src.width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if(cuda_ret != cudaSuccess) FATAL("Unable to copy from device");
}

void verify(Matrix M, Matrix  N, Matrix P) {

  const float relativeTolerance = 1e-6;

  for(int row = 0; row < N.height; ++row) {
    for(int col = 0; col < N.width; ++col) {
      float sum = 0.0f;
      for(int i = 0; i < M.height; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < M.width; ++j) {
            int iN = row - M.height/2 + i;
            int jN = col - M.width/2 + j;
            if(iN >= 0 && iN < N.height && jN >= 0 && jN < N.width) {
                sum += M.elements[i*M.width + j]*N.elements[iN*N.width + jN];
            }
        }
      }
      float relativeError = (sum - P.elements[row*P.width + col])/sum;
      if (relativeError > relativeTolerance
        || relativeError < -relativeTolerance) {
        printf("TEST FAILED\n\n");
        exit(0);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("TEST PASSED\n\n");

}

void freeMatrix(Matrix mat)
{
    free(mat.elements);
    mat.elements = NULL;
}

void freeDeviceMatrix(Matrix mat)
{
    cudaFree(mat.elements);
    mat.elements = NULL;
}

void startTime(Timer* timer) {
    gettimeofday(&(timer->startTime), NULL);
}

void stopTime(Timer* timer) {
    gettimeofday(&(timer->endTime), NULL);
}

float elapsedTime(Timer timer) {
    return ((float) ((timer.endTime.tv_sec - timer.startTime.tv_sec) \
                + (timer.endTime.tv_usec - timer.startTime.tv_usec)/1.0e6));
}
```

Comment: If your code isn't producing correct results, then posting incomplete, uncompileable code is no help to anyone. There is a chance that the error lies in code you have chosen not to post. Your code contains no API error checking. Are you sure that there are no runtime errors being generated? What happens if you run your program with cuda-memcheck

Comment: I edited the original post to include that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One set of problems is here:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M_h, M_c,FILTER_SIZE*sizeof(float));
```

If you ran your code  with `cuda-memcheck` it would point you right at this line as being a problem.

1. The first parameter should be the *destination symbol*, i.e. `M_c`, and the second parameter should be the host source pointer, i.e. `M_h`.
2. Furthermore, shouldn't it be `FILTER_SIZE*FILTER_SIZE` ?  Isn't the size of data you want to transfer equal to the dimension squared?
3. Finally, `M_h` is not a valid source pointer.  You should use `M_h.elements`.

So something like this:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M_c, M_h.elements,FILTER_SIZE*FILTER_SIZE*sizeof(float));
```

I don't believe this fixes all the issues in your code.  To continue the debug, I would print out one element in the GPU result that does not match your `verify` routine, and work through the arithmetic for that one element.  Use `printf` in device code if that helps.

In the future, please run your code with `cuda-memcheck` before asking for help here.  Even if you don't understand the output, it will be useful for those trying to help you.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to help. This is the first I've heard of memcheck, so I will be doing some research and use that in the future. Thank you.